# How can i change a Value by pressing on a button with setOnAction?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to javaFX and i am trying to programming a graphical calculator.
Now i want to know if there is a way to change a value by pressing a button with setOnAction?

```
public class exampleFX extends Application{

  public static void main(String[] args){
  launch(args);
  }
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

 int value=0;
    Button button = new Button();

    // just as an example i do know i can't change a variable in a lambda expression
    button.setOnAction( e -> value +=1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a local variable (declared within a method). Local variables cannot be reassigned a new value within a lambda expression or anonymous class. (They must be either final, or effectively final.) The basic idea is that the lambda expression `e -> value+=1` is going to be executed at a later date (when the button is pressed), by which time the variable is out of scope (the enclosing `start()` method will have completed). While there are ways the language authors could have made this work, it is somewhat counter-intuitive to change the value of a variable that no longer appears in scope, so it is not allowed.

The simplest fix is thus to make the variable an instance variable. The following compiles:

```
public class ExampleFX extends Application{

    private int value = 0 ;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button button = new Button();

        button.setOnAction( e -> value +=1);

    }
}
```